# pyinstaller fails saying it cant find pyexcel.ext.ods but is included several times

Tags: python, linux, pyinstaller

Im trying to build an executable in linux. I have built my .spec file to include everything from the warning text. I have not barely come close to a successful build. I figured I could weed out the unnecessary library's after I get a good compile. I have finally compiled without any debug errors. Thanks to installing 64 bit
`sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0`

When I run the program from the terminal I'm getting the an error that I should not be getting. I have included `pyexcel.ext.ods` in the spec file because it was in the warning.txt file as well as the top of my script declared as `import pyexcel.ext.ods` as well as the separate function file. The error is coming from the function file that I imported the functions from. The error is below.

```
LOADER: executable is /home/thisGuy/Desktop/keep/keep
LOADER: homepath is /home/thisGuy/Desktop/keep
LOADER: _MEIPASS2 is NULL
LOADER: archivename is /home/thisGuy/Desktop/keep/keep
LOADER: Extracting binaries
LOADER: Executing self as child
LOADER: LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/thisGuy/Desktop/keep
LOADER: executable is /home/thisGuy/Desktop/keep/keep
LOADER: homepath is /home/thisGuy/Desktop/keep
LOADER: _MEIPASS2 is /home/thisGuy/Desktop/keep
LOADER: archivename is /home/thisGuy/Desktop/keep/keep
LOADER: Already in the child - running user's code.
LOADER: Python library: /home/thisGuy/Desktop/keep/libpython2.7.so.1.0
LOADER: Manipulating evironment
LOADER: PYTHONPATH=/home/thisGuy/Desktop/keep
LOADER: PYTHONHOME=/home/thisGuy/Desktop/keep
LOADER: Manipulating Python's sys.path
LOADER: importing modules from CArchive
LOADER: extracted struct
LOADER: extracted pyi_os_path
LOADER: extracted pyi_archive
LOADER: extracted pyi_importers
LOADER: Installing import hooks
LOADER: out00-PYZ.pyz
LOADER: Running scripts
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 5, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyi_importers.py", line 270, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "/home/thisGuy/Dropbox/python/myPy/keep/build/keep/out00-PYZ.pyz/cDTf", line 4, in <module>
  File "/home/thisGuy/Dropbox/python/myPy/keep/build/keep/out00-PYZ.pyz/pyexcel.exthook", line 117, in load_module
ImportError: No module named pyexcel.ext.ods
LOADER: RC: -1 from keep
LOADER: OK.
LOADER: Cleaning up Python interpreter.
LOADER: Back to parent
LOADER: Doing cleanup
LOADER: Freeing archive status for /home/thisGuy/Desktop/keep/keep
```

My first question is how to make the above error go away? I have included the `pyexcel` library as well as the `pyexcel.ext.ods` at the head of every file in direct not conditional `imports`
my spec file looks like this. I know its overkill! I know I dont need pydoc etc... But I included every warning just to be safe.

```
# -*- mode: python -*-
a = Analysis(['keep.py'],
             pathex=['/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyexcel',
            '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyexcel_io',
            '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyexcel_ods',
            '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyexcel_xls',
            '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ezodf',
            '/home/thisGuy/Dropbox/python/myPy/keepLinux'],
             hiddenimports=['_dummy_threading',
            'pydoc ',
            'bdb ',
            'nt',
            'nt',
            'pyexcel.sheets.load_from_memory',
            'pyexcel.ext.xls',
            '_emx_link',
            'msvcrt',
            'collections ',
            'pyexcel_io.DEFAULT_SHEETNAME',
            'hashlib ',
            'pyexcel.sheets.Matrix',
            'pyexcel._compact ',
            'nt',
            'pyexcel.io.BytesIO',
            'pyexcel_io.SheetWriter',
            'pyexcel_io.BookReader',
            'EasyDialogs',
            'pyexcel.ext.ods',
            'optik',
            'rourl2path',
            'pdb ',
            'pyexcel.sheets.transpose',
            'rourl2path',
            'optparse ',
            'pyexcel.sheets.Sheet',
            'pyexcel_io.SheetReaderBase',
            '_winreg',
            'encodings ',
            '_subprocess',
            '_dummy_threading',
            'doctest ',
            'pyi_archive ',
            'pyexcel.sheets.load_from_dict',
            'pyexcel.sheets.SeriesReader',
            'pyexcel_io.SheetReaderBase',
            'pyexcel_io.SheetReaderBase',
            'optik',
            'pyi_importers ',
            'io.StringIO',
            'io.BytesIO',
            'pyexcel.exthook ',
            'org',
            'warnings ',
            'msvcrt',
            'pyexcel_io.SheetWriter',
            'tokenize ',
            'pickle ',
            'pyexcel_io.BookReader',
            'pyexcel.sheets.NominableSheet',
            'pyexcel_io.DEFAULT_SHEETNAME',
            'pyexcel_io.NamedContent',
            'ordereddict',
            '_sysconfigdata_d',
            'pyexcel.io.get_writer',
            'pyexcel.sheets.get_sheet',
            'pyexcel_io.BookWriter',
            'pyexcel_io.BookWriter',
            'pyexcel_io.BookWriter',
            'nt',
            'email ',
            'cl',
            'pyexcel.sheets.load_from_django_model',
            'pyexcel.io.BytesIO',
            '_scproxy',
            '_subprocess',
            'pyexcel.io.StringIO',
            'pyexcel.sheets.Reader',
            'pyexcel_io.BookWriter',
            'EasyDialogs',
            '_sysconfigdata_d',
            'pyexcel_io.BookReader',
            'pyexcel_io.SheetWriter',
            'pkgutil ',
            'unittest.loader ',
            'cl',
            'dis ',
            'pyexcel_io.BookReader',
            'org',
            'ordereddict',
            'pyexcel_io.DEFAULT_SHEETNAME',
            'pyexcel.ext.ods',
            'pyexcel_io.NamedContent',
            'unittest.main ',
            'pyexcel.sheets.ColumnSeriesReader',
            'pyexcel_io.BookWriter',
            'msvcrt',
            'pyexcel.io.StringIO',
            '__future__ ',
            'org',
            'dummy_threading ',
            'ordereddict',
            '_scproxy',
            'msvcrt',
            'pyexcel.sheets.load',
            'pyexcel.ext.xls',
            'pyexcel_io.NamedContent',
            'cl',
            'SOCKS',
            'pyexcel.sheets.load_from_records',
            'pyexcel_io.BookReader',
            '_emx_link',
            '_winreg',
            'gettext ',
            'pyexcel.io.load_file',
            'pyexcel.sheets.load_from_sql',
            '_winreg',
            'ordereddict',
            'SOCKS',
            '_compact '],
             hookspath=None,
             runtime_hooks=None)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='keep',
          debug=False,
          strip=None,
          upx=True,
          console=True )
coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               strip=None,
               upx=True,
               name='keep')
```

Any ideas for fixing my import issue?  It would seem as though I have been pretty comprehensive in my .spec file to the point of overkill.

Comment: 'pyexcel.ext.ods' makes sense only in pyexcel's context because of pyexcel.exthook. Outside pyexcel, you probably want to use 'pyexcel_ods'. And potentially, all pyexcel.ext.* need to converted to 'pyexcel_'. Please give it a 'go' as I have not done this before.

Comment: @chfw, Not sure exactly what you mean? Tried `import pyexcel.ext.*` at the head of my documents but that fails with 'SyntaxError: invalid syntax'.
The `pyexcel_ods` is listed in the `paths=` in my .spec file. Im not sure where `pyexcel.exthook` file is located? I did included `ezodf` in my `paths=` and that may have solved it? I have a new set of errors being thrown and cant be sure till I sort that out. If you have any suggestions on how to create a hook file 'of all the pyexcel dependency’s'  for pyinstaller id like to write, test it and submit it so others can benefit. 
Thanks chfw

Comment: @chfw. the error is pointing to pyexcel/io/csvbook.py? in included the `_compact.py` in my hiddenimports in the .spec file, but error persists. 
File "/home/thisGuy/Dropbox/python/myPy/keepLinux/build/keep/out00-PYZ.pyz/io.csvbook", line 24, in <module>
ValueError: Attempted relative import beyond toplevel package

Any ideas? As always thanks.